# C++ , Regular expression

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I know how to find regular expression in specific string. How to find first element that match with regular expression?

Here is my code:

```
QString mangledText;
QRegExp rx("string");
while ((pos = rx.indexIn(mangledText)) != -1){
 mangledText.replace(pos, rx.matchedLength(), "replaced string");      
}
```

I want to replace first match result (or second or third) instead of all of that.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to replace first match result instead of all of that.

Use an `if` instead of a `while`.

```
if ((pos = rx.indexIn(mangledText)) != -1){
   mangledText.replace(pos, rx.matchedLength(), "replaced string");    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but is there general solution for that? 
if I want to replace third result , how do I am?

Comment: `QRefExp::indexIn` takes an offset also. You can start with an offset of `0`. In the subsequent searches, use `pos + rx.matchedLength()` as the offset.